# Finding roots : $x-7\sqrt{x}+10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, exponentiation

> Find all possible roots of $k(x) = x-7\sqrt{x}+10$

I am having serious trouble rearranging this function as $ax^2+bx+c$ since it has $'-7\sqrt{x}'$. Can anyone please help me? Little help would really be appreciated.

Comment: $x-7\sqrt{x}+10=\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2-7\sqrt{x}+10$

Answer (score 5):

WLOG $\sqrt x=y\implies x=y^2$

For real $y,x\ge0$

So we have $$y^2-7y+10=0$$

The problem could be more interesting had one of the roots been $<0$

Answer (score 0):

$$
x-7\sqrt{x}+10=0
$$
$$
u^2 -7y+10=0
$$
$$
a=1, \quad b=-7, \quad c=10, \quad u = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.
$$
After you find $u,$ recall that $x=u^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Factorize whenever possible: $x-7\sqrt{x}+10=(\sqrt x-2)(\sqrt x-5)$ from where the solutions follow immediately.